# Firefox doesn't play audio

Tags: sound, firefox, 15.04, hdmi

To be clear, the audio on my laptop is working just fine. Other applications in Ubuntu play sounds as expected. Firefox, however, won't output any audio through the native speakers or headphones. There is one exception: when I use HDMI from PC to TV then Firefox audio correctly plays through TV.

I'm new to Ubuntu so please respond with step-by-step instructions geared at beginners. Thanks!

Comment: If 15.04 is like 14.04, you can go to System Settings --> Sound and select the Applications tab. With FF and audio supposedly playing, how are the settings there?

Comment: CubebUtils + shows volume level...  still no sound.

Comment: Thank you. Wondering why this is still not fixed in 2019. It's indeed alwasy a problem when disconnectin HDMI. Couldn't pavucontrol just be a tab on the sound settings? It's already preinstalled, but hard to find for the average user.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If you install an app called **"[pavucontrol](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol/)"**, (direct link **apt://pavucontrol** ) you can look at which applications are playing audio, and which device they are sending audio to on a per-application basis.

Because (as far as I know) firefox does not have any way to select an audio output device, if you change the output device for an application it will retain that information.... my guess is that at some point you, or someone else (or some application) has selected HDMI audio for firefox, and that has been stored.... you just need to change it back to the default device.

Comment: Has saved me as well. Never heard of "PulseAudio Volume Control" before!

Comment: Me too! For me, the PulseAudio Volume Control revealed that "for Firefox" the volume was all the way down and this is why I could not hear anything while watching a YouTube video in Firefox. Thanks James!

Comment: Similar thing happened to me, I played it through HDMI yesterday but now I am not able to change firefox sound output to headphone. How to do it ? Even in sounds settings I have already chosen built in speakers and VLC is able to play music. Please Help

Answer (score 13):

Run:

```
rm -r ~/.config/pulse; pulseaudio -k
```

This will clear hdmi settings and settings will be back to default.

Note that this may delete other manual pulse configuration too.

Comment: I did this and it worked after a reboot. Reboot may not have been required, may be just a Firefox restart. Anyhow, it is working again! Thank you.

Comment: Worked for me, had to reboot my computer though. Closing/opening FF was not enough for me. Thanks

Comment: This worked and I didn't have to restart firefox or the machine.

Answer (score 12):

Long story short:

change audio output device to something else and then back to the desired device

---

Full version:

I know it's bit outdated, but still. I've just run into similar problem on Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 - everything worked apart Firefox. I remember lately using my laptop with TV via HDMI and changing sound output to it. Today, in my "Sound" application, I had only one position available: "Speakers - Built-in audio". Plugging in headphones to my dock or socket on laptop's side didn't change a thing.

I managed to get it working with some workaround - I suspected that if I will be able to choose something else from the output devices list and then back to "Speakers - Built-in audio", Firefox will be updated with this info. Luckily, I had some USB speakers in the office and it did the trick - new device appeared on the list so I switched to it - sound was working. Back to "Speakers ..." - working.

It looks like some small bug (or maybe that's intentional) when there is only one device on the list, it doesn't refresh selection when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be caused by certain Firefox Add-Ons. I disabled all of mine, then restarted Firefox and the sound now works. You can turn them on one at a time to see which is causing the problem.